# Is it possible to re-factor a code first migrated database into multi-database system?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a MVC 5 project in  asp.net. While creating the project code first migration was enabled, now with the time data increased to around 4-5 GB. Now I dont want to lose the data. But to gain performance I have to refactor the single database into multiple. 
The simplest way I can think of is copy the database, then delete the database and refactor and copy the data.

But thats not a way developer should do.. :)
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Amount of data shouldn't matter. Are you talking about the complexity of the design (lot's of entities and relationships?). Take a look at bounded contexts https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

Comment: There are many many ways to gain performance. Splitting up the database into many smaller ones isn't among the obvious ones. Since this is hardly a programming issue (as you say yourself) this question isn't on-topic at Stack Overflow. I suggest you take a look at [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, lemme go through the links, will get back :)